# Prove or disprove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-2,1)} \frac{(1-\cos{((y-1)^2x)})(x+2)}{(x+2)^4+(y-1)^4}=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove or disprove that this limit is $0$:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(-2,1)} \frac{(1-\cos{((y-1)^2x)})(x+2)}{(x+2)^4+(y-1)^4}$$

(Wolfram Alpha says it doesn't exist)

As a "clue" it is suggested that I find $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos{t}}{t^2}$$

,which is $\frac{1}{2}$, but I really don't know how this might help me. I tried approching $(-2,1)$ along $x=-2$ to transform it into the second limit, but that $x$ inside the $\cos$ is very annoying.

I also tried using the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition and find an $\epsilon$, such that no $\delta$ exists, but again I've never used this before, so I get nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent (by letting $x':=x+2$ and $y'=y-1$) to prove or disprove that the limit 
$$\lim_{(x',y')\to 0 } \frac{\left(1-\cos\left(y'^2\left(x'-2\right)\right)\right)x' }{ x'^4+y'^4}   $$
is $0$. Using the mentioned clue, we are reduced to determine whether the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}  \frac{xy^4\left(x-2\right)^2}{x^4+y^4} $$
is $0$ or not. But we can rewrite
$$\left| \frac{xy^4\left(x-2\right)^2}{x^4+y^4} \right|=\left|x\left(x-2\right)^2\right|\underbrace{\frac{y^4}{x^4+y^4}}_{\leqslant 1}.        $$

Comment: Mmm, but the first limit doesn't exist ([link to Wolfram](https://goo.gl/WzYAAV)), while the second does, and is indeed 0 ([link to Wolfram](https://goo.gl/aS0w4u))!